# Parameters in the init method of a AlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to know if there is a way to pass parameters in the constructor of a UIAlertView different from those in initWithTitle. In particular I would like to pass an NSArray. is it possible?
This is the code:

```
@implementation UIAlertTableView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {


    array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Capitaliz. semplice",@"Capitaliz. composta",@"Pagamenti rateali",@"Bond", nil];

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero  style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    table.delegate=self;
    table.dataSource=self;


    [self addSubview:table];
}
return self;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see your call to UIAlertView in that code - only the creation of the array ...

Comment: what you want to pass in alert view a massage string(that's what all we do), and yes you can pass that easily.

Comment: What do you expect the alert view to do with this array?

Comment: did you end up finding an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you ask yourself a question like that, search for "[UIClassName] class reference"

UIAlertView class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

It's init takes an NSString, not an array of strings:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate     cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

Comment: you can override the method initWithTitle?!

Comment: You could either inherit from and extend it with your own methods or use categories to extend.  You can't override since that implies the same signature with an overridden implementation

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks anyway:

```
#import "UIAlertTableView.h"



@implementation UIAlertTableView

@synthesize tableSelected,fontSize;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    c=0;    

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero  style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    table.delegate=self;
    table.dataSource=self;


    [self addSubview:table];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)rect {
if (c==0) 
    c++; 
else if(c==1){
    if([tableSelected isEqualToString:@"categorie"])

        array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Capitalizzazione semplice",@"Capitalizzazione composta",@"Pagamenti rateali",@"Bond",  nil];

    else if([tableSelected isEqualToString:@"tassi"])

        array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Tasso effettivo annuo",
               @"Tasso effettivo mensile",
               @"Tasso effettivo bimestrale",
               @"Tasso effettivo trimestrale",
               @"Tasso effettivo quadrimestrale",
               @"Tasso effettivo semestrale",
               @"Tasso nominale convertibile mensilmente",
               @"Tasso nominale convertibile bimestralmente",
               @"Tasso nominale convertibile trimestralmente",
               @"Tasso nominale convertibile quadrimestralmente",
               @"Tasso nominale convertibile semestralmente",
               nil];

    else if([tableSelected isEqualToString:@"rate"])


        array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Rata annuale",
               @"Rata mensile",
               @"Rata bimestrale",
               @"Rata trimestrale",  
               @"Rata quadrimestrale",  
               @"Rata semestrale",  
               nil];
    [table reloadData];
    [table selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
    c++;
}
[super setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, 300)];
self.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 480/2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The poster has solved his problem another way. But yes a simple category will work and work well. It can be implemented this way.

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitlesArray:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles{
    if ((self = [self initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil])){
        for (NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles) {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This method takes a final parameter. An array of `NSStrings` and iteratively adds buttons with the titles of the strings.